# Keyboard controls stop working after I click a button in the JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

My keyboard controls stop working after I click a button in the Graphical gui panel (JPanel) that I created. Below is the code for my main class. I put my keylistener code in the controller class. I tried to set the keyboard focus but it's not working. I have also added my JPanel class code. I tried setting the focus on that as false and it's still not working. Can someone please explain why the focus is not shifting from the buttons please?

Main class

```
    Graphical gui = new Graphical(view, getPlayer());
    frame.add(gui, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    // Get keyboard focus.
    frame.requestFocus();
    view.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler(view));

    controller = new Controller(world.getPlayer());
    frame.addKeyListener(controller);
```

JPanel class

```
public class Graphical extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private UserView view;
private Snowman snowman;
private Game game;

public Graphical(UserView view, Snowman snowman) {
    this.view = view;
    this.snowman = snowman;
    initComponents();

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.println("You are now playing as a snowman!");
    snowman.changeCharacter1();
    jButton1.setFocusable(false);
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.println("You are now playing as a jellyfish!");
    snowman.changeCharacter2();
    jButton2.setFocusable(false);
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.exit(0);
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    new Game();
}                                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of a `KeyListener` if you're having focus issues. Often times when you have a lot of Swing components the component that your `KeyListener` is registered to can lose focus.

I don't know if `setFocusable(false)` on the buttons would cause you to regain focus of the component you registered with the `KeyListener` but I know it's not recommended. I suppose you could force focus from the other components but that wouldn't scale very well in the long run.